# C# I want to check if a string contains a german date with two dots

Tags: c#, string, date

I have the string "24.04.2013".

How can I recognize if the string is a date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `"..24042013"` ok? How about `"24..042013"`? Or `"24042013.."`?

Comment: Well if its really a string with date then you should use `DateTime.TryParseExact` so you know its a date or not and if it contains your so called 2 dots or not

Comment: @Matthew I changed the question.

Comment: Did I get the down-votes for not knowing regex?

Comment: @kame - its probably because it doesn't show research effort

Comment: @kame I didn't downvote, but I think it's because you didn't post some code showing what you tried. (Personally, I never downvote without posting a comment saying why.) Also: I anticipated your question and answered it already below. ;)

Comment: @Sayse At least I researched it, but didn't showed it. Right. Thank you!

Comment: @kame, i didnt downvote either, just taking a guess at why

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
int count="24.04.2013".Count(c => c == '.');
```

Comment: I am still a C#-beginner. Where do I find more information about the meaning of (c => c == '.') ?

Comment: @kame http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx, especially the *Lambdas with the Standard Query Operators* section.

Answer (score 3):

I think your real question should be: How do I validate a date?

You should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms131044.aspx) to validate it.

For example:

```
CultureInfo enDE = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); 
string dateString = "24.04.2013";

DateTime date;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd.MM.yyyy", enDE, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Failure");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use

`string.Split('.').Length >= 2`

Comment: No, German dates don't use commas.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Ah i got it confused with the currency

Answer (score 2):

You can match the string with a regular expression (RegEx). That not only gives you whether there are two points, but also if the format is correct: 2 digits, point, 2 digits, point, 4 digits.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}");
if (regex.IsMatch(myInput, regex))
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

possible to check it via regex!

```
    private static bool IsDateGerman(string germanDate)
    {
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"[0-3]?[0-9]\.[0-1]?[1-9]\.[0-9]{1,4}");

        return rx.IsMatch(germanDate);
    }
```

still didnt handle all cases like 39.19.2013